# Audio en vivo con Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Hice una aplicación para enviar audio en vivo con Socket.io. El problema es que solo funciona entre pestañas en la misma ventana de Chrome. Cuando trato de enviar o recibir audio desde otro pc o incluso desde otra ventana, aparece este error:

```
GET blob:https://server/ce74cfe7-bb9c-40b0-9cb0-1138b22b1b11 404 (Not Found)
```

Este es el codigo en main.js (de la página):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io("https://server:4000", verify=false);
    socket.on('audio stream', function(blob){
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = blob;
    });
    $('#ptt').click(function(){
        micOn();
        document.getElementById("ptt").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ptt-off").disabled = false;
    });
    $('#ptt-off').click(function(){
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        document.getElementById("ptt").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ptt-off").disabled = true;
    });
    function micOn(){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        var constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: false
        };
        var video = document.querySelector('video');

        function successCallback(stream) {
            window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
            var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            socket.emit('audio stream', myName, blob);
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
        }

        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
});
```

Este es el código en el servidor (index.js):

```
socket.on('audio stream', function(blob){
    socket.broadcast.emit('audio stream', blob);
});
```